# ServiceBase - Background threads not getting created?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

So we're currently on a .NET Core Console App, which is supposed to run as a background task in on a customer's Windows Server machine. As such, we have implemented a `DataService` class, that implements `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`.

Previously, we simply created a new thread, and utilized a infinite `while()` loop (and `Thread.Sleep()`) to "achieve" the background task. Some time later, we switched to using `System.Threading.Timer` and using the functionality from there to achieve what we needed. This worked perfectly!

However, a few days ago, this all stopped working. The functionality itself is tested & works (tested via manually calling the callback function, running it on the main thread). However, when trying to create a new thread (with or without using `System.Threading.Timer`), nothing happens. A thread does not seem to be created at all according to VS2019's Debug -> Thread window either, if that is to be trusted.

As I'm sure you can imagine, this is yet another thing that's having us very lost. Any and all help appreciated!

[Minimal repo (though not runnable online due to using/implementing ServiceBase](https://repl.it/repls/QuintessentialShowyWireframe)

Comment: Can you post a minimal repro of the issue?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Will get on that now and link it to the OP, though I'm afraid something very odd/unexplainable is going on with our environment and doing it outside our own environment will have completely different "results".

Comment: And learning that would be a useful outcome.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Without a doubt, but it's difficult to learn from something when you have absolutely no idea what's going on, when it once worked and for seemingly no reason doesn't anymore.

Comment: Try storing the `System.Threading.Timer timer` in a private field, to prevent it from being garbage collected.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Have been tested previously resulting in no change, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you move that MCVE in your question, please? Did you try adding a Log message calls directly on entering the OnStart method? IOW did you confirm OnStart is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the program is supposed to run as a service (via implementing `ServiceBase`), the issue was mostly related to just that and MSSQL. After some logging & troubleshooting, and granting *sysadmin* permissions to *NT\SYSTEM* the issue was resolved.